# API REST with Grails 2.5.6: How to config URIs without UrlMapping? As a notation on the method?

Tags: api, rest, grails, uri

I have a Rest API with Grail 2.5.6 and I am implementing some improvements and best practices. In this case I need to implement the rule:

- *Use kebab-case for URLs*
- *Bad: /systemOrders o /system_orders*
- *Good: /system-orders*

I know that I can configure the UrlMapping file for each method and I solve it. But I understand that there should be some notation on the method that allows me to conigure was URI.

In the grails 4.0 documentation I see the following example:

```
@Get("/search?limit=25&media=music&entity=album&term={term}")
SearchResult search(String term)
```

For **Grail 2.5.6** is there an alternative similar to **@Get**?

Answer (score 0):

Finally with trial and error, I found the solution. I leave you the example of how it was and how the controller turned out.

Before:

```
 class LoginController {
 static allowedMethods = [userInfo: 'GET']
   
   def userInfo() {}

}
```

Now:

```
 class LoginController {
 static allowedMethods = ['user-info': 'GET']
   
   def "user-info"() {} // <-- here is the change

}
```

By defining the method name in quotation marks I could implement *kebab-case*.